# EF core order by navigation property

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core-3.1, ef-core-3.1

I have an entity relationship like this.

```
public class Provider
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        public string LastName { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<ProviderPod> ProviderPods { get; set; } = new List<ProviderPod>();
    }
```

```
public class ProviderPod
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int ProviderId { get; set; }
        public int PodId { get; set; }

        public virtual Provider Provider { get; set; }
        public virtual Pod Pod { get; set; }
    }
```

```
public class Pod
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<ProviderPod> ProviderPods { get; set; } = new List<ProviderPod>();
    }
```

I need to order the 'Provider' entity by it's navigation property ProviderPods' "Name" separated by a comma. Something like this

```
IQueryable<Provider> entityQuery = context.Providers.AsQueryable();

//Need to enter Appropriate query below 
entityQuery = entityQuery.OrderByDescending(x => string.Join(", ", x.ProviderPods.Select(y => y.Pod.Name)));

var list =  entityQuery.Take(12).ToList();
```

What would be the best way to achieve this ordering?

Comment: Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
What have you tried?

Comment: @PapaAtHome thanks. Sorry for the quality of the question, this is my first time asking. I haven't found any clear way achieve the sorting.

Comment: @Mededi Hasan Shuvo: No need to be sorry. I have made te same mistake in the past. I hope you will enjoy SO.